# AddForceExplosion only affects y axis unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon"))
    {
        rb.AddExplosionForce(knockbackStrength, transform.position, 5f, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
       
    }
}
```

So the object only gets thrown into the air. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm surprised the object moves at all because the explosion is occurring at what appears to be the center of mass (assuming `rb.centerOfMass` is the default `Vector3.zero`). Try `rb.AddExplosionForce(knockbackStrength, other.transform.position, 5f, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);` to have the explosion originate at the weapon's position.

Comment: @Ruzihm It works! Thank you!

but i have the problem that is use Photon and when i do the AddExplosionForce the player moves and then gets teleported to the Position he was before.

Comment: that sounds like it would be more appropriate for [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Then you can include some more information about how to reproduce that problem including how you have Photon configured.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the object moves at all because the explosion is occurring at what appears to be the center of mass ( `transform.position` is the center of mass when `rb.centerOfMass` is the default of `Vector3.zero`).

To have the explosion originate at the weapon's position, use `other.transform.position` instead:

```
rb.AddExplosionForce(knockbackStrength, other.transform.position, 5f, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```